# Working with quantum mechanics spins

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I've written the following code for simple quantum mechanics operators on spin states:

[image]

It seems to work, but the output could be better - how do I let Mathematics know that $0**\ 0==0$, and can I let it compress the up/down ket to have only the 2 arrows, not the "$**$" in between?

Comment: You can use `Bra`, `Ket` and you can `Unprotect` `NonCommutativeMultiply`.

Comment: Do you have details about Bra and Ket? I can't seem to find much documentation about these two in Mathematica's help itself...

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  As far as I know they're `Head`s with no meaning (unless you give them meaning!) that simply render very nicely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unprotecting and giving meaning to `**` (`NonCommuntativeMultiply`) will do the trick:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply]
NonCommutativeMultiply[H___, 0, T___] := 0
```

Comment: Very nice! Didn't know that... thanks for the tip!